# PowerMockito mocking constructor for specific case and not others

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermock, powermockito

I'm using PowerMockito when writing JUnit tests. There is a section of legacy code i am trying to test. part of the method has the following code:

```
try(ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileLocation)))
{
    handleZipDir(rootDir, directoryToZip, zos);
}
```

I want to mock the "new FileOutputStream(zipFileLocation)" call and can successfully do that with powerMockito.

The problem is that I only want to mock this one call. There are other sections of the code that call "new FileOutputStream(...)" that i don't want to mock, and instead want it to call the real constructor.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this with PowerMockito.

Does anyone know how to mock a specific call to a constructor but not others?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these that works best for your scenario:

`PowerMockito.whenNew(ZipOutputStream.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(myMockZipOutputStream);`

or

`PowerMockito.whenNew(ZipOutputStream.class).withArguments(any(FileOutputStream.class).thenReturn(myMockZipOutputStream);`

Comment: I already tried this, Unfortunately i can't do this. The zipFileLocation will not be an accessible location so it will throw an exception when creating the parameter FileOutputStream.  The point of this one test is to ensure the code can handle this special zipFileLocation so i can't change that either.